# Display polygon on Map (Process geometries WKT-format)

Tags: here-api

**Edit:** Working solution.
(Works with the changes made by DevBab).

**Extra:** added an option to style the Polygon. (var polyStyle)

```
var url = 'http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json' +
                '?app_id='+ app_id  +
                '&app_code=' + app_code +
                '&prox=' + lat +','+ lng +',1000' +
                '&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1' +
                '&level=county'+
                '&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,county';

$.getJSON(url,function (data) {
     var location = data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location;
     var wktShape =  location.Shape.Value;

    var polyStyle = {
        strokeColor: 'red',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3',
        lineWidth: 2
    };

     var geoPoint = H.util.wkt.toGeometry(wktShape);
     map.addObject(new H.map.Polygon(geoPoint,{style:polyStyle}));                                  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a polygon, not a marker, so modify this:

```
map.addObject(new H.map.Marker(geoPoint));
```

by that:

```
map.addObject(new H.map.Polygon(geoPoint));
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it out tomorrow when I´m on my PC.